# Do While and While Loops not working in C++ code

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

Hi I'm writing a C++ code that asks the user for an input as to which internet service provider package they are using, and then using that information the code calculates their monthly bill. However the following code is not working.

```
{
int choice;     
double hours;       

cout << "Which Subscription package have you purchased? 1, 2, or 3? " << endl;
cin >> choice;

switch (choice)
{
case 1:
    cout << "How many hours were used this month? " << endl;        //Package A
    cin >> hours;
        do{     
                cout << "Please enter a valid number of hours used. " << endl;
                cin >> hours;
            } while (hours < 0 || hours > 744);

        double monthlyBill; //Calculated as base price + additional hours

        if (hours >= 11 || hours <= 744)
            monthlyBill = 9.95 + (hours * 2.00);
        else
            monthlyBill = 9.95;

        cout << "Your monthly bill is : $";
        cout << monthlyBill << endl;
        break;

case 2:         //Package B
    cout << "How many hours were used this month?" << endl;
    cin >> hours; 
    while (hours < 0 || hours > 744);       //Input validation
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid number of hours used. " << endl;
        cin >> hours;
    }

    double monthlyBill_b;   //Calculated as base price + additional hours

    if (hours >= 21 || hours <= 744)
        monthlyBill_b = 14.95 + (hours * 1.00);
    else
        monthlyBill_b = 14.95;

    cout << "Your monthly bill is: $ ";
    cout <<  monthlyBill_b << endl;
    break;

case 3:         //Package C is a flat rate of $19.95 per month
    cout << "Your monthly bill is $19.95";
    break;
default: cout << "You did not enter 1, 2, or 3. ";
    break;
}
}
```

When run, the code displays the following :

> Which Subscription package have you purchased? 1, 2, or 3?
>
> 1
>
> How many hours were used this month?
>
> 14
>
> Please enter a valid number of hours used.

If any one could provide some insight as to why this isn't working that would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do{     
    cout << "Please enter a valid number of hours used. " << endl;
    cin >> hours;
} while (hours < 0 || hours > 744);
```

Should be re-written as:

```
while (hours < 0 || hours > 744) {     
    cout << "Please enter a valid number of hours used. " << endl;
    cin >> hours;
}
```

In former case you are entering the while unconditionally and then prompting the message and reading new value (unconditionally).

The correct way would be to enter the loop only when the input is out of range.

Comment: I tried that before, you can see the exact code which you wrote under case 2. Neither of them work at the moment.

Comment: Check [former](http://ideone.com/fxnwKB) v/s [later](http://ideone.com/bHQ1us). This indeed fixes the problem.

Comment: I've updated my code according to your suggestions, and I am still encountering the same problem, did I miss a part of your code that has been changed?

Comment: Make sure you save new file(s) and compile the latest code. Delete old executatble and try again. Does your code work fine for package 2?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It turns out the error was a small syntax one, the problem was in ` while (hours < 0 || hours > 744); {

                cout << "Please enter a valid number of hours used. " << endl;
                cin >> hours;
            }`

Comment: The ; just after the while statement was causing all the problems. Thanks once again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing:

```
while (hours < 0 || hours > 744) {
    cout << "Please enter a valid number of hours used." << endl;
    cin >> hours;
}
```

This is because you have already asked for hours (cin >> hours;) before the do-while loop executes. In this case, you want a while loop that does the check immediately after you cin >> hours. A do-while loop will execute everything in its block before doing the check on whether that block of code has to be executed again.